# Dynamically change html labels based on selection in a combo box

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a JavaScript which fills the values in the dropdown. Based on the selection in the dropdown, I need to update the label of the next combo box.

JavaScript is as follows:

```
onLoad: function(){                 
......
label.innerHTML = this._Strings.abcd_TableLabelMount;
this.disks.refreshHeader();
this._formatSelect.store.root.options.length = 3;
this._formatSelect.store.root.options[0].text = "NTFS";
this._formatSelect.store.root.options[0].value = "ntfs";
this._formatSelect.store.root.options[1].text = "FAT32";
this._formatSelect.store.root.options[1].value = "fat32";
this._formatSelect.store.root.options[2].text = this._Strings.abcd_None;
this._formatSelect.store.root.options[2].value = "-1";
this.xyzVal.invalidMessage = this._Strings.abcd_InvalidDrive;
}
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="input_field">
<label class="label required" for="${id}_ABCD_XYZ" id="${id}_ABCD_XYZ_LABEL">${_Strings.abcd_TableLabelMount}</label>
<input id="${id}_ABCD_XYZ" dojoAttachPoint="xyzVal" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true" maxLength="30" size="32">
```

If the user selects the option NTFS, I need to display the label `${_Strings.abcd_TableLabelMount}` as 'NTFS' for the next combo box and so on.
Can you suggest a better way to do the same?

Comment: Are you using dojo? and which version? and with dijit too?

Comment: Yeah... using dojo 1.6 with dijit too

Comment: are you looking for this effect? http://i.imgur.com/Gc0tZ5I.png

Comment: Im lookin for this kind of effect http://imgur.com/IyzpDPa

Answer (score 0):

I think you search something like this : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/TextBox.html#getting-and-manipulating-the-value

Regards